# count where values appear in another table sql

Tags: sql

I have a form that I want to find out how many people who fill in the form have an account.

The form goes into an SQL table and has a column for the email address and I want to compare it with the column in another table that contains all of the accounts.

**table1: (form entries)**

email_address

- john@hotmail.com
- mary@hotmail.com
- ann@hotmail.com
- john@hotmail.com
- peter@hotmail.com

**table2: (customer account table)**

email_address

- john@hotmail.com
- ann@hotmail.com
- james@hotmail.com

I need an SQL to tell me how many people from table1 had an account. In this example the answer would be 2.

I got this far but when I tested it on a few different tables I got some results higher than the amount of accounts I had:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  COUNT(email_address)
FROM
  table2
WHERE
  EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 
   FROM table1 
   WHERE table1.email_address = table2.email_address );
```

Comment: Please specify database engine you're using in tags

Comment: Thanks for updating, it's actually inside a low code platform that allows lookups into SQL databases and I'm pretty new to SQL.

Comment: I mean there could be differences between database engines in terms of SQL syntax. It would be good if you specify the one you're trying to use.

Comment: Which dbms?????

Answer (score 1):

`distinct` should be inside `count()` :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.email_address) 
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM table2 t2
              WHERE t1.email_address = t2.email_address
              );
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a plain join:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.email_address)
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.email_address = t2.email_address;
```

This assumes that the email address in the second table is unique, on the grounds that an account would likely only be registered once.  If so, then the inner join would filter off all email address entries which did not have accounts.

See the @Yogesh answer if you want to keep using the `EXISTS` approach.

Comment: I was going to [add a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84f38f/1), but SQLFiddle appears to be suffering from bugs at the moment.  The distinct count isn't zero, it's really two.

Comment: Thanks very much!